# Return the name of a saved file in Databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have a notebook in Databricks that does some transformations and writes a parquet file to Azure Data Lake Storage. At the end of the notebook I would like to be able to have an exit parameter with the name of the parquet file that the notebook have just saved. I would like to use this parameter in Azure Data Factory later.

In general I would like to have a copy activity in Azure DataFactory, which moves the just saved parquet file to a database table. The thing is that the name of the parquet file changes every time the notebook is ran. Let me know if there is a better solution to this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: How does this notebook defines the name of this file when saving to ADLS?

Comment: How about giving the same parameter to both Databrick notebook activity and Copy activity? This parameter would hold the location where you want to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

The below code would be sending the file name back to ADF.

dbutils.notebook.exit(filename)